# suggestion needed to retrieve details of the release branch from GIT

Tags: git

I am looking to get all the filenames for a particular release and check if we have the latest committed files in the release branch.

The below command gives all the filenames in the release branch

```
git ls-files
```

I can then loop in the filenames as per the below command, to get the commitID|Author|commit Date|Commit Message.

```
git log -1 --source --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d" --all --pretty="~|%h|%an|%ad|%s|" $filename
```

How can I get the filename and parent branch(the branch from which the code is merged to release) as an output to above command.

Also, I want to verify if the file is present in any other feature/bug fix branch and not yet merged. One way is that I can loop the above command with all the branches created for particular month(we have month *YYYYMM* as naming convention of branch) and then compare if the latest modification is not present in the release branch. Any better way to do this?

Comment: You mixed up terminology. `git ls-files` shows in-tree **files** of the specific tree state (defined by different types of Git **objects**). **Object** is something very different in Git terminology.

Comment: thanks , modified the query

Comment: You rather need to iterate over all branches and see if they have been merged to the release.

Comment: Thanks 0andriy!  I want to know the last modification branch which is having the object . Is there any parameter in --pretty which can be used to find the corresponding branch  name.e.g if I do git log -1 --source --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d" --all --pretty="~|%h|%an|%ad|%s|" $filename

Comment: Thanks 0andriy!  I want to know the lastest modification branch for the corresponding filename . Is there any parameter in --pretty which can be used to find the corresponding branch name.e.g if I do git log -1 --source --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d" --all --pretty="~|%h|%an|%ad|%s|" $filename                                                                                 then it gives me the entire history with the latest branch for corresponding filename.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. If we remove --all then it will show only the file committed in the particular branch. I can loop for all the branches and determine the latest commit.

```
git log -1 --source --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d" --pretty="~|%h|%an|%ad|%s|" $filename
```